# Output field as text in Odoo View

Tags: python, odoo-8, odoo, qweb

Straight to question.
Can we output a field as text only in Odoo View?

```
    <record id="view_of_a_model" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">the_name_of_the_view</field>
        <field name="model">a.beautiful.model</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <sheet>
                    How to output fields as text here?
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I want to add more explanation. What I wanted is something like...

```
<a href="http://localhost/DSLNG/dbo_View_PatientVisit_list.php?qs=??????put the field as text here??????" target="_blank">Open record in other application</a>
```

Sorry for confusion

PS : It seems that people think that using field tag is the way to go. But using field tag will display the field as input when in Edit mode. What I want is display it as text, regardless of the current view mode.

Answer (score 3):

**Text in odoo view**

**Python code:**

```
notes = fields.Text(string='Notes')
```

**XML view:**

```
<record id="view_of_a_model" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">the_name_of_the_view</field>
    <field name="model">a.beautiful.model</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <sheet>
               <i>notes</i> ===> Text here 
                <field name="notes" />
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: In edit mode the field will be displayed as input. I need the field displayed as text only regardless of what the view mode is. Do you know how?

Comment: @strike_noir: still an open question!?

Comment: @SiL3NC3 I haven't found the correct way to do this. The only way I used was normal Odoo field with readonly True.

Comment: @strike_noir: what I figured out is, when you trying to use values in form or tree, then you are possibly "breaking" odoo logic. If you want to render just some values, you need to create a new widget (template) and add this by calling an action for it.

Comment: I agree. Creating a custom widget is the way to go.